# String reverse function

Tags: algorithm, c, strings

Are there more optimization possible in this code to achieve better performance and minimal memory usage?

```
#include<stdio.h>
char * strrev(char* str)
{
     int length=0;
     char* str1=str;

     while(*str++)
        ++length;

     str=str1;
     char  temp;

     for ( int i=0; i< length/2; ++i)
     {
           temp= *(str +i);
           *(str +i) = *(str+length -1-i);
           *(str+length -1-i)= temp;
     }

     return str1;
}
int main()
{
    char str[]="Hello World!";
    strrev(str);
    printf("Reversed str:%s", str);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is... use the native libraries...

Your code here:

> ```
>  int length=0;
>  char* str1=str;
>
>  while(*str++)
>     ++length;
> ```

counts the number of chars until it finds the null terminator.

This is an inefficient way of doing it, 1 byte at a time. A much more efficient way to do it is to work on word-sized memory chunks - 32-bits and 64-bits on respective platforms. If you do a fold of the 8-bit bytes using bitwise operators on the value, you can identify whether there is a null byte in fewer CPU operations than by processing each byte individually. If this sounds complicated, [well, it sort of is](http://www.stdlib.net/~colmmacc/strlen.c.html), but, on the other hand, it is already done for you:

```
#include <string.h>

....

    length = strlen(str);
```

That will likely halve the time needed to find the string length.

Then, your code would be a lot easier to read if you used array-like subscripts to access the chars instead of pointers..... that way you can get rid of the `str1` variable as well:

```
 char  temp;

 for ( int i = 0; i < length/2; ++i) {
       temp = str[i];
       str[i] = str[length - 1 - i];
       str[length - 1 - i] = temp;
 }
```

If you want, you can reduce that to a while-loop with converging indices:

```
 int right = length - 1;
 int left = 0;
 while (left < right) {
     temp = str[left];
     str[left++] = str[right];
     str[right--] = temp;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't pointer arithmetic faster than array_like subscripts? Or will it be into category of pre-mature optimization and decent compiler will take care it?

Comment: @Steephen: You're correct that pointer manipulation is usually faster than array subscripting, however it's worth measuring with your compiler on your computer to be sure.